# Getting Robot to Point to Correct Direction

Tags: python, opencv, arduino, path-finding, robotics

I am commanding a robot from a base station with radio. Base station takes location/orientation information from an overhead camera using the AR tag on the robot (with openCV). Moreover, base calculates the path robot should take to reach the target from location information (A* with each grid being 30 by 30 pixels in camera). My robot can only turn left/right (on its central point) and go forward/backward. Robot includes an Arduino Uno with two Lego NXT motors.

I use the following code to get robot to point at right direction. However, when the robot gets close to the angle that it is supposed to travel to, instead of stopping an going forward it tries to fix its orientation infinitely.

```
    def correctOrientation(self, rx: int, ry: int):
        #returns direction robot needs to point.
        direction = self.getDirection((self.sx, self.sy), (rx, ry))
        #method to stop robot.
        self.comms.stop()

        anglediff = (self.angle - direction + 180 + 360) % 360 - 180

        while not (abs(anglediff) < 15):
            #Decides which way to turn.
            if self.isTurnLeft(self.angle, direction):
                self.comms.turnLeft()
            else:
                self.comms.turnRight()
            #Put sleeps because there is a delay in camera feed. Allows it to get the location right
            time.sleep(0.3)
            self.comms.stop()
            #Updates position
            self.getPos()
            time.sleep(1)
            #Calculates orientation of robot and updates it
            self.angle = self.calcOrientation()
            anglediff = (self.angle - direction + 180 + 360) % 360 - 180
            print(anglediff)
            time.sleep(1)
```

My helper function that are used. I calculate orientation of robot by using two points known on the robot and drawing a line in between those two point. Hence, line becomes parallel with th orientation.

```
    def isTurnLeft(self, angle, touchAngle):
        diff = touchAngle - angle
        if diff < 0:
            diff += 360
        if diff < 180:
           return False
        else:
            return True

    def calcOrientation(self) -> float:
        return self.getDirection(self.marker[0], self.marker[3])

    def getDirection(self, source: Tuple[int], target: Tuple[int]) -> float :
        return (math.degrees(math.atan2(target[1] - source[1], target[0] - source[0]))+360)%360
```

I can't figure out if my code is problematic in logic. If so what can I do about it? If code is fine and the problem is the delay/setup of the system, what are the other ways I can control the robot?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Hard to tell exactly with only this fragment of code. But my guess is that if the motor is already turning left, then just let it run, not to repeatedly setting it again and again with `self.comms.turnLeft()`. The `if self.isTurnLeft(self.angle, direction): self.comms.turnLeft()` looks redundant to me, or explain what you expect it to do?

Comment: Does it move back and forth to try and fix it's location? If so, then maybe it's overshooting the 15 degrees difference. Try sleeping a shorter time of rotation. Better still: make the rotation time dependent of the anglediff. Larger anglediff, rotate longer.

Comment: Also, are you logging any values? A simple `print` of angle values will help you understand what happens, as you can follow along.

Comment: I have logged some values. It seems my angle calculations were a bit off. However, because of the way I do turning it takes a lot of time to get the robot in the right direction. I have made the sleetime depend on the anglediff as you have said which made it better.

EDIT: What are other options I can try for this purpose? Are on board direction compasses reliable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by changing the image library for AR tag recognition. We were using 2 tags for one robot. It is significantly slower and fail prone to detect two tags. Updated it to only have one tag. Moreover, switched from angle based calculations to vector based which is way simpler to understand.